# Does unbinding bubble in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

If I bind an event to an element in jQuery, do I always have to unbind it from the exact same element I bound it to? Can I unbind from a child or a parent? I am also using an event namespace - does this have any bearing on the situation?

```
<div id="id1">
    <div id="id2">
        <div id="id3">
            hello
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


$("#id2").bind("click.mynamespace", function() { alert("hi!");});
$("#id1").unbind("click.mynamespace"); //will this work?
$("#id3").unbind("click.mynamespace"); //will this work?
```

It doesn't seem to be mentioned anywhere in the jQuery documentation.

Comment: What happend when you tried it ?

Comment: from a quick check within SO itself and the firebug console, it seems that these statements don't work:

>>> $("#question").bind("click.myname", function(){alert("hi");});
jQuery(div#question.question✉)
>>> $(".post-text").unbind("click.myname");
jQuery(div.post-text)
>>> $(document).unbind("click.myname");
jQuery(Document does-unbinding-bubble-in-jquery)

Still, clicking anywhere within the question triggered the event.

Comment: aargh newlines in SO are not preserved in comments but hopefully you get what I mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not an event and thus does not bubble. All event-related functions will act on *exactly* the elements in the jQuery object.

If you want this behaviour, simply select all elements:

```
// element and its children
$('#id1').find('*').andSelf().unbind('click.mynamespace');
// element and its parents
$('#id3').parents().andSelf().unbind('click.mynamespace');
```

On a side-note, `.bind()` and `.unbind()` are kind of deprecated as of jQuery 1.7 - better use `.on()` and `.off()` instead (same arguments in your case).

Comment: Thanks. And we're still using jQuery 1.6 in my organisation :)

Comment: Consider updating. Often it works without any changes to your code.

Comment: partly it's because things are deprecated and we want to be able to say we are not using deprecated code. In fact, even jquery.com is using a 1.4.x version of jquery.

Comment: To be honest, "we don't want to use any deprecated functions we are using for a long time now" is a pretty bad argument. They still work fine and not using a new version because of that is well... not developer-friendly. Besides that, the only functions that were **really** deprecated are  `.live()` and `.die()` - both are not used that often and easily replaced.

Comment: actually, we do use `.live()` quite a lot to ensure that events are correctly bound to content when it is loaded as part of an AJAX request